# How to resize label control

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, label

I'm trying to allow user to resize a label (the control, not the font) before printing it.

For this I'm using a LabelPrint class and I've set AutoSize property to false. I already made a code that would adjust font size to my label size. But I can't change the label size… Thanks for help, here's the code.

```
class LabelPrint : Label
{

    public LabelPrint()
    {
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        this.AutoSize = false;
        this.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 12);
        this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(this.SizeLabelFont);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == 0x84)
        {  // Trap WM_NCHITTEST
            var pos = this.PointToClient(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32()));
            if (pos.X >= this.Size.Width - grab && pos.Y >= this.Size.Height - grab)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(17);  // HT_BOTTOMRIGHT
        }
    }
    private const int grab = 16;


    public void SizeLabelFont(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Only bother if there's text.
        string txt = this.Text;
        if (txt.Length > 0)
        {
            int best_size = 100;

            // See how much room we have, allowing a bit
            // for the Label's internal margin.
            int wid = this.DisplayRectangle.Width - 3;
            int hgt = this.DisplayRectangle.Height - 3;

            // Make a Graphics object to measure the text.
            using (Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics())
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
                {
                    using (Font test_font =
                        new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, i))
                    {
                        // See how much space the text would
                        // need, specifying a maximum width.
                        SizeF text_size =
                            gr.MeasureString(txt, test_font);
                        if ((text_size.Width > wid) ||
                            (text_size.Height > hgt))
                        {
                            best_size = i - 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Use that font size.
            this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, best_size);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add this in LabelPrint class:

```
        protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
    {
        base.OnLayout(levent);
        base.AutoSize = false;
    }
```

But I still get the same problem: AutoSize is set to false so when i increase the fontsize, i can't see all my label.Text but I can't resize the label itself… I mean with the mouse and ResizeRedraw().

Comment: What exactly happens? Is there any error or exception? *I can't change the label size* is a bit too broad...

Comment: As a user of the program when I try to change a label size I just can't… I see the resize cursor but I can move my mouse as i want it does nothing… I'm doing it about the same way that I did to resize a picturebox (and it works well for the picturebox)

Comment: Try overriding `OnLayout`. Call `base.OnLayout(e)` then `base.AutoSize = false`. Setting `AutoSize = false` in the constructor won't set the property.

Comment: Thanks I edited my post with the changes made. It's still not working… :(

Comment: It's a Label. That control has some *issues* in relation to sizing/autosizing. You can override its default behaviour, but I think it's way simpler to derive your class from `Control` and perform the Text painting yourself (possibly using `TextRenderer` and its flags to align the text). If you derive from `Control`, I think the sizing handle will work immediately as expected, but of course, for example, `BorderStyle` and `TextAlign`, won't be available anymore. You'll have to implement them from scratch. Or, you could derive from `Panel`. Some considerations about the Text.

Comment: BTW, the Font measure you're currently implementing is bound to *explode* if the Control's size gets too small.